# SELinux blocking procmail from executing dspam but no AVC message

Tags: selinux, procmail

I have a CentOS 7 system in which I use postfix as the MTA. Certain users use procmail via `.forward` in their home directories:

```
# cat .forward
"|exec /usr/bin/procmail -f- || exit 75"
```

In this case, I am having difficulty figuring out why SELinux will not allow procmail to execute dspam from `.procmailrc`:

```
:0fw: dspam.lock
| /usr/bin/dspam --client --stdout --deliver=spam,innocent
```

In the procmail log I get:

```
procmail: Locking "dspam.lock"
procmail: Executing "/usr/bin/dspam,--client,--stdout,--deliver=spam,innocent"
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/dspam: Permission denied
procmail: Program failure (126) of "/usr/bin/dspam"
procmail: Rescue of unfiltered data succeeded
procmail: Unlocking "dspam.lock"
```

However, if I set SELinux to permissive mode it works fine.

The problem is that it's not logging any AVC messages about what is being denied. When I was first setting things up I found some gaps via `audit2why` and `ausearch` and fixed them. Now I get nothing, even though it's clearly SELinux that is preventing it from working.

Edit: Here is the dspam binary:

```
# ls -lZ /usr/bin/dspam
-r-x--s--x. dspam mail system_u:object_r:dspam_exec_t:s0 /usr/bin/dspam
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having a very similar issue. In my case selinux is quietly preventing code in my .procmailbin folder from executing (I have already set the default context for .procmailbin to procmail_exec_t).

I have no quite solved the issue yet, but I believe the path to the answer is to instruct selinux to report *all* denials, which it does *not* do by default.

To enable full reporting of all denials use the following:

```
semodule --disable_dontaudit --build
```

Review audit.log and use sealert as appropriate to determine what is going on.

Then to return things back to normal when done use:

```
semodule --build
```

Good luck! In my case I'm at the point of sealert showing me this info which was not appearing before:

```
SELinux is preventing sh from search access on the directory /home/chris/.procmailbin.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that sh should be allowed search access on the .procmailbin directory by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'sh' --raw | audit2allow -M my-sh
# semodule -X 300 -i my-sh.pp
```

... but I still need to review if this is the actual problem and what the best solution is.

Update: So, it turns out this solved the issue for me.

Here are the contents of the custom module I built:

```
# more procmailbin-sh-search.te

module my-sh 1.0;

require {
        type dmesg_t;
        type procmail_t;
        type procmail_exec_t;
        type abrt_t;
        class dir search;
        class process noatsecure;
}

#============= abrt_t ==============
allow abrt_t dmesg_t:process noatsecure;

#============= procmail_t ==============
allow procmail_t procmail_exec_t:dir search;
```

Seems to me this should be the default behavior so I guess I'll see if I can figure out who to report this "bug" to.

Comment: Accepting this because even though it didn't directly answer my question, it did point me to figuring it out. Once I added `--disable_dontaudit` I actually got the info I needed to update my policy. Thanks for the hint, and for sharing your troubleshooting approach!

Answer (score 0):

So after looking at Chris Bennett's answer I used `semodule --disable_dontaudit` and was able to figure out what I needed. Here is what I ended up with to make postfix+procmail+dspam work:

```
require {
    type dspam_rw_content_t;
    type dspam_t;
    type dspam_exec_t;
    type procmail_t;
    class dir { open read write getattr add_name search };
    class file { append getattr lock open read write setgid };
    class unix_stream_socket connectto;
}

#============= dspam_t ==============
allow dspam_t dspam_rw_content_t:dir { open read write getattr add_name search };
allow dspam_t dspam_rw_content_t:file { append getattr lock open write };

#============= procmail_t ==============
allow procmail_t dspam_exec_t:file { open read setgid };
allow procmail_t dspam_t:unix_stream_socket connectto;
```